# Instantiate public object inside method

Tags: java, oop

I'm trying to  instantiate an object inside a method of a class so it can be used anywhere in the class. I come from a python background and it is quite easy, you can just pass the instantiated object to an instance of it's "self" like below.

```
self.camera = CameraInstance()
```

How do you do this in Java? I tried something like below but it doesn't like it.

```
private void init_camera_settings() {
    public CameraInterface camera;
    camera.TakePhoto()
}

private void someotherMethod() {
    camera.TakePhoto()
}
```

Both methods are in the same class. The reason for this is because I only want to instantiate the camera object only in certain scenarios.

Thanks!

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/index.html

Comment: @HarshPoddar a member variable is NOT a global variable. There is no such thing as a global variable in Java.

Comment: In `init_camera_settings` did you intend to initialize the variable rather than calling `TakePhoto`?

Comment: Hint: you start by reading good books or online resources covering such basic essentials of the Java language. Yes, stackoverflow is helping with programming problems; but the idea is that you do prior research. The idea is not that you use SO as replacement for google or as an alternative to studying yourself. This is not meant to be rude; just so that you understand that SO is not "programming school" and doesn't exist to explain things to you that are perfectly documented all over the place.

Comment: @JBNizet Erm, wouldn't a public static field be considered global variable?

Comment: @yshavit To a certain degree, public statics are global variables. But keep in mind that you can still have more than one classloader in use; thus theoretically, and I *believe* that this leads to the fact that you can also have multiple copies of a public static field. So in that sense, you are not "global" any more in such situations.

Comment: @Jägermeister Classloaders complicate things, for sure. But if the class is in your "root" classloader (not the actual RootClassLoader, which I think is a JVM thing, but the one that contains all of the `-cp` classes from when you launched the app), then that one should always win -- and its public static fields will still be global for most reasonable uses of the word. So yeah, to really make it global you need to make sure you launch java correctly in terms of it class path, and I guess a purist attitude could be that from the static compilation's perspective, it's not really global.

Comment: @yshavit no. They are still scoped to a class, and need to be statically imported or scoped with the class they belong to in order to be used. Unlike, for example, in JavaScript where you can define `var foo = 'bar'`, and use foo wherever you want (including when you actually meant `boo` and made a typo).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use the variable throughout the `class` in different methodsm the variables should have class scope.  You usually use `new` to create a new Object

```
public MyClass {

    public CameraInterface camera = new Camera ();


private void init_camera_settings() {
    camera.TakePhoto()
}

private void someotherMethod() {
    camera.TakePhoto()
}
}
```

Comment: I understand that the convention-violating method names come from the questioner; but still ... worth pointing out, too.

Answer (score 4):

You can't declare a field inside a method. In Java, a type either has a field, or it doesn't. Every instance of the same class has the same set of fields.

But you can declare the field (not in a method) and decide to only assign a *value* to it in a method:

```
// Note: avoid public fields
public CameraInterface camera;

private void initCameraSettings() {
    camera = new Camera();
}

private void someotherMethod() {
    camera.takePhoto();
}
```

(The field will have a default value, in this case `null`, until you assign a different value to it.)

As an aside, I'd *strongly* advise against public fields. I make every field private, and add properties to allow access where necessary. This allows you to change implementation details later. The one exception to this is `public static final` fields of immutable types, basically for constants, but even there I'd be cautious.

Comment: One might add that there is sometimes the need for public final static fields.

Comment: ...only assign a value to it in a method - surely you don't mean this `private  CameraInterface camera = new Camera ();`

Comment: @ScaryWombat: No, I mean what I've shown. I've clarified the wording a bit.

Comment: @Jägermeister: Edited.

Comment: I don't see what `static` has to do with immutable types. Did you mean `public final` like `Array.length`?

Comment: @Gendarme: No, I meant public static final like various constants exposed like Math.PI.

Answer (score 0):

```
self.camera = CameraInstance()
```

is equivalent to:

```
class Foo {

    private CameraInstance camera;

    public Foo() {
        this.camera = new CameraInstance();
    }

    // use "this.camera" in methods.
}
```